# Is this the right entry for the sudoers file to give php access to reload nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, sudoers

I need to give php access to reload nginx. The command is `nginx -s reload` so is the entry in the sudoers file below correct?

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: nginx -s reload`

Then would `<?php exec('sudo nginx -s reload'); ?>` or shell_exec be the function to use?

Thanks

Comment: Would this be from within a script running on the web server?  Because while I can't say for sure, common sense dictates that a script killing and restarting the server that's running it probably isn't a smart move.

Comment: @GordonM Maybe not. Nginx doesn't actually handle PHP stuff, and actually hands it off (acting like a proxy, really). In particular, if he's using php-fpm or php-cgi (the common ways to handle php in nginx), they handle spawning threads to exec the script. He would be safe in killing/restarting nginx.

Comment: @GordonM, yes it would be from a script running on the web server (nginx). I appreciate the comment about common sense but if you weren't sure why not check what does nginx -s reload do. It's different than /etc/init.d/nginx restart which as you know will kill and restart the server. We are running php-fpm and need to reload nginx occasionally to load new settings without restarting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the absolute path to nginx, but your syntax looks correct.
You would use `shell_exec()`

Comment: Thanks I thought I needed to run nginx -s reload specifically but using the absolute path I just saw I can execute nginx reload without the -s flag.